# Does every Lords including Lord Shiva worship each other in different scriptures? Why?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, gods, goddess

Does every Form of God worship Other Forms like Shakti worships Vishnu and Vishnu worships Shakti?

Is it true for Lord Shiva also?

What is the reason?

Comment: There is no evidence from the critical edition of Valmiki Ramayana that Rama worshipped Shiva. I have not heard of Matsya, Kurma, Varaha, Narasimha, Vamana worshipping Shiva.

Comment: yes, Lord Shiva worships Lord Rama according to some Vaishnavas and worships Lord Vishnu according to some Vaishnavas. Shaivas believe that He worships none and is worshipoed by all

Comment: Court needs the evidence of the incident.But their is no evidence of measure of one's love.In one purana it is mentioned that the one who considers vishnu and shiva are biggest fools as they are one and the same with different roop.

Comment: This question has been edited too much?

Comment: @AkshayS The original question was not a duplicate, edit had made it a duplicate.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria The original one was marked duplicate before the edit for your information

Comment: @Partha No, editing history shows question was marked duplicate after edit to the original question.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria at least i remember editing after it was marked duplicate

Comment: @Partha Yes you edited after it was marked duplicate, I am talking about the first edit to the question which was done by OP himself which changed the question completely which is why the question is still marked as duplicate.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria okay thanks so mch.kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats  true.

This is common for each form of God .Let us take some examples:

1.Ganeshashtakam says:

> Yataschaviraasit jagat sarvametat tathaavjaasano vishvago visvagopta/Tathendradayo devasangha manushyah sadaa tam Ganesham namamo bhajamah meaning: I always prostrate and worship Lord Ganesha, who is the origin of the universe and of Brahma (Abjaasana), Vishnu (Visvagopta), Indra and men (Stavakusumanjali, Swami Gambhirananda (ed), Udbodhan, page 154. The next sloka says Shiva is also born from Ganesha (Ibid page 155).

2. Sri Jagannatha(Vishnu)-Ashtakam says:

> Ramaa-Shambhu-Brahmaa-Surapati-Ganesha-archiapada, meaning tge feet of Lord Jagannatha is worshipped by Lakshmi, Shiva, Brahmaa, Indra and Ganesha.(Ibid. page 268).

3.Shivastakam says:

> Vidhi-Vishnu-shioddhrita-paadayugam pranamaami Shivam Shivakalpatarum, meaning I prostrate to Shiva whose feet are held by Brahma and Vishnu (Ibid page 168-9).In this stotra Shiva is the source of all.

4.Surya-pratah-smarana-stotra says:

> saamani yasya kiranaan prabhavaadihetum brahma-hara-atma-kamaalakshamchintyahetum meaning that Surya is the source of Brahma, Shiva and Vishnu (Stavananjali,R.K.Math Nagpur, page 84).

5. Dakshina-Kalika-stotra says:

   > vadamaste kimvaa janani vayam uchchair jadadhiyah na dhata naapisho harirapi na te vetti paramaam meaning that Devi is beyond perception of Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva.(Stavakusumanjali, page 305).

This is allowed in our tradition. This is called Ishtanistha. Also known as 'Nahi-ninda-nyaaya' so far as I know.

After illumination, each saint realises that "Ekam vedam vibabhuba sarvam" The Same one is expressed as many.